# Getting SocketTimeOutException while accessing webservice with Large data(~ >900 kb)

Tags: android, web-services

When i'm trying to fetch small data using webservice...everything works fine
But i got issue when i'm trying to access Large Data(~ >900 kb).
I tried by giving several TIME_OUT like 60000,120000 but nothing helped me.

Can Anyone tell me how to overcome this?
Reply will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This looks like a bad data/internet connection.